# Extract and Concatenate multiple instances of strings from column that match a regex expression

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I have a dataset similar to the following dataset:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT ';000d6a11,Adult' AS Policy
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ';0003ga21,Child' AS Policy
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT ';000d6a11,Adult;;0003ga21,Child' AS Policy
```

| Policy |
| --- |
| ;000d6a11,Adult |
| ;0003ga21,Child |
| ;000d6a11,Adult;;0003ga21,Child |

I want to return the following:

| Policy | PolicyNo |
| --- | --- |
| ;000d6a11,Adult | 000d6a11 |
| ;0003ga21,Child | 0003ga21 |
| ;000d6a11,Adult;;0003ga21,Child | 000d6a11,0003ga21 |

I have tried using `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL()` however this returns the PolicyNo on multiple rows and does not remove the ; before the second instance of the PolicyNo:

| Policy | PolicyNo |
| --- | --- |
| ;000d6a11,Adult | 000d6a11 |
| ;0003ga21,Child | 0003ga21 |
| ;000d6a11,Adult;;0003ga21,Child | 000d6a11 |
|  | ;0003ga21 |

The query I have used is:

```
 WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT ';000d6a11,Adult' AS Policy
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ';0003ga21,Child' AS Policy
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT ';000d6a11,Adult;;0003ga21,Child' AS Policy
  ) SELECT Policy 
    ,REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(Policy, ';(.+?),')
FROM CTE
```

How can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```sql
ARRAY_TO_STRING(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(Policy, ';([^;,]+),'), ',')
```

where

- `;([^;,]+),` captures into Group 1 any one or more chars other than `;` and `,` (excluding them from the value)
- `ARRAY_TO_STRING` will create a single comma-separated string from the found matches.